# Flutter - how to make popup disapears when there a multiple popups?

Tags: flutter, dart, popup, navigator, flutter-alertdialog

My problem is pretty straightforward.

I click on a button, then popup1 shows up, then I click on a button on popup1 and popup2 shows up, I click on a button popup2 and popup2 disapears, BUT popup1 is still there.

How do I make popup1 also disapear when clicking on a button on popup2 ?

NB: I am referencing the AlertDialog widget when talking about popups.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click on button from Popup 1 to Open Popup 2, you need to call pop method to pop Popup 1 after opening popup 2.Add below code to pop Popup 1.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you got a simple example of how I hide the Dialog and do a function after.

```
return showDialog(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) {
                  return AlertDialog(
                    title: Text("test title"),
                    content: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: ListBody(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("test data"),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      MaterialButton(
                        child: Text('Ok'),
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          doFunction();
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
```